# Apache storm on Microsoft Azure

Tags: linux, windows, azure, apache-storm, azure-hdinsight

We have two flavors of Apache Storm on Windows Azure. One is a Linux-based cluster and the other one is windows. I know that if i'm a .NET specialist i need to go for windows based cluster. I need to know which one is better if i need to process million messages per second?.

Answer (score 1):

They will scale similarly and you should pick the operating system you are most comfortable with. The main advantage with Linux is that there is a larger community working with it so more third party tools will be built for Linux.